# Google Sheet Scripts: set value in a column when pushing a button for each row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, javascript-objects

I would like to be able to set a value in a column, based on a formula to create that value, when someone presses a button in my sheet.

Right now this works but it keeps overwriting the value in cell G22 (which is of course normal since its hard-coded).

How can I resolve this?

```
function CopyValueCell() {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("UTM 1.0");
    
    var AG1val = sheet.getRange('D16').getValue(); // get the value of AG1
    
    sheet.getRange("G22").setValue(AG1val); // set the value of AG1 to G22
    
}
```

Comment: What's your goal? To write it under the last value in column G? Or to write in column G of the same row you're positioned?

Comment: I want to add the value of D16 in column G starting at the 21st position until the end of that column. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
function CopyValueCell() {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("UTM 1.0");
    
    var AG1val = sheet.getRange('D16').getValue(); // get the value of AG1
    var rows = sheet.getLastRow() - 21 //determines how many rows are going to have that value
    var values = []
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++){values.push([AG1val])} //creates the array with as many items as rows needed
    
    sheet.getRange(22,7,rows).setValues(values); // set the value of AG1 to G22 until the end of the sheet
    
}
```

Comment: PS: I noted that in your code you called it AG1 value but you take the value of D16

Comment: Yes this is a solution, however it now fills all the rows instead of only one per click.
Also it overwrites any lines above it, and indeed I made a naming mistake on my end. It should fill column G with the value of D16, one row at the time starting from 21 until the end of the sheet.